# find custom post type post by searching its custom field with my string

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, search, query-posts, meta-query

I have a custom post type called `series` and each post has a custom field named `originaltitle`. So in my code before I create a new post, I need to check if there is already a "series" with same `originaltitle` custom field value.

If it exists, then return that post ID. If not, then I can move on with my code.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the post using `get_posts()` and the meta query (in my example, I used `meta_key` and `meta_value`) like so:

See the function [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) for more details on the parameters (and other examples that might help you), but the `'fields' => 'ids'` means that the function will return only the post IDs and not full post object/data.

```php
<?php
// Find a "series" post with the meta originaltitle set to a specific value.
$ids = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'      => 'series',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'meta_key'       => 'originaltitle',
    'meta_value'     => 'put value here',
    'fields'         => 'ids',
) );

$post_id = array_shift( $ids );

// Or you can do something like:
/*
if ( ! empty( $ids ) ) {
    $post_id = $ids[0];

    // run your code
}
*/
```

Comment: thanks that works!